# in iOS 4.3, how i can differentiate between the background mode, when you press the home button or when you press the on/off button?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, mode

I already use the:

```
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {}
```

method, but I can't differentiate if is because press the home button or the on/off button.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

For the on/off button(or an incoming call or SMS):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

For the Home button:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

With the notification of `applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidBecomeActive` will still enter while you are entering in background. But there is a way to differentiate by getting the state of the app, so try this in `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

```
- (void)appHasGoneInBackground {       
    bool inBackground = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;

    // lockScreen state
    if (!inBackground) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

[Apple's UIApplication-class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {}` when your app is entering the background (home button) and `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` when it's about to be closed (on/off button or iOS call to close after a random time in background).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you lock or unlock your iOS device your application delegate will call `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`, respectively.  Locking and unlocking are similar to receiving an interruption like a phone call. Sending your application to the background by hitting the home button calls different methods, namely `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` and `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`.